# exclude from display field so only logged in user can view?

Tags: views

I am trying to make it so logged in users can delete images they've added to a gallery created in views but I don't want the field link to content to be viewable by anonymous.
So I have added the field in my views gallery link to content but have selected exclude from display. I remember years ago there is a way to set up a gallery in views so you end up with an add and delete content page for users by grouping this field and a few other advanced settings but it was so long ago cannot find the tutorial.

How can I have this field of link to content in views only viewable by logged in users?

Comment: not sure on your set up based on that description, but see here (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10316/how-to-show-a-view-field-depending-on-roles) for a possible solution

Comment: thanks, without time ended up just giving users a find content available to delete any images.